# How to make last column of datatable visible=false when no data is there in the table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable

```
 var table=$('#Table').dataTable({
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bsorting": true,
    "iDisplayStart": 0,
    "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]],
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "bServerSide": true,

    "sAjaxSource": "Area/Controller/Action",

    "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {

        aoData.push({ "name": "pageStatus", "value": "onload" }
            );
        },
    //mdata : I am using here
    //Also I am using column filter plugin

    }
});
```

### Problem

My table doesn't have any data on the page load and the table is having 12 columns. I am trying to execute the following:

```
table.fnSetColumnVis(0, false);
        table.fnSetColumnVis(1, false);
        table.fnSetColumnVis(2, false);
        table.fnSetColumnVis(3, false);
        table.fnSetColumnVis(4, false);
        table.fnSetColumnVis(5, false);
        table.fnSetColumnVis(6, false);
        table.fnSetColumnVis(7, false);
        table.fnSetColumnVis(8, false);
        table.fnSetColumnVis(9, false);
        table.fnSetColumnVis(10, false);
        table.fnSetColumnVis(11, false);
```

The last statement causes JavaScript error`Unhandled exception at line 1511, column 5 in localhost:50718/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js 0x80070057 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid argument.`

I am using datatable 1.9.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What Error? Please be more specific.

Comment: @mainguy the error is : Unhandled exception at line 1511, column 5 in http://localhost:50718/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js

0x80070057 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid argument.

Comment: you sure that you having 12 columns . given the error link of your local host doesn't show us the error (localost:portno is system specific) .try to setup a sample fiddle . cheers

Comment: I am getting the error " 0x80070057 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid argument" in Datatable.js file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because you try to delete columns sequentially.

Deleting a column is basically refers to the current state of the table.

If there are 3 columns [1,2,3], you try to delete 1st column `table.fnSetColumnVis(1, false);` -- resulting table with 2 columns only.[2,3]

Deleting 2 would delete the last column and leaving you with 1 column [2]